# OPTLINK: Warning 23: No Stack

Tags: compiler-construction, d, windows-7-x64

I'm using the DMD compiler on Windows 7. I just tried to create a brand new D file and compile it, and would get a *gigantic* error dump from DMD. Eventually, I pared the file back to literally just the module declaration (`module tournament;`), and then I get the following errors from DMD:

```
OPTLINK : Warning 23: No Stack
OPTLINK : Warning 134: No Start Address
```

Now, I have absolutely no idea what could be causing this. Could someone help me? The command I used was `dmd tournament.d` in the same directory as the file being compiled.

Comment: How did you install DMD?

Comment: Seems like you don't pass file with `main` function to DMD or don't have `main` at all.

Comment: Thanks Robik, that fixed it just fine. Is there a compiler switch for DMD for adding a stub ``main`` to whatever its compiling?

Comment: You can add `-main` to add a stub main. But in your case, where I guess that you only want to compile the code and not link, using `-c` is better as explained in CyberShadow's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is coming from the linker - by default, after compiling the modules you specified, the compiler will invoke the linker to link the object files into an executable. If the modules you specified do not contain an entry point (main function), the linker will complain. You can suppress invoking the linker by supplying the `-c` switch to the compiler.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21576437/21501) for more information.